# How do I create a 1-to-Many Transform Stream in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I am trying to replace an ETL process using NodeJS streams. The Transform stream I am attempting to write takes in a dataset, and based on configuration data, will output one or more records per record inputted. In other words, if it's reading 100000 records, the transformation can end up writing anywhere from 100000-400000 records. The `_transform` method only allows its callback to be called once, so I am trying to figure out how to output multiple objects per single input object.

I looked at duplexes but every example I saw was using it as a two way flow, whereas I definitely want my stream to be one way (or i may just not understand how they work). Anyone have any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback can only be called once, but the `.push` method is what emits data, and can be called as many times as necessary in the `_transform` method. Example:

```js
class MyTransform extends Transform {
  _transform(chunk, enc, next) {
    const arrayFromChunk = chunk.split(',');

    arrayFromChunk.forEach(piece => {
      // this.push is what will emit readable data, can be called as often
      // as needed.
      this.push(piece); 
    });

    next(); // next can only be called once.
  }
}
```

docs here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream

Comment: while this did solve my problem, it introduces a new one. this.push returns a boolean on whether or not the next writable stream is ready to take on more data. In this example that boolean is being ignored.

For anyone else who comes across this, I found this github post which addresses both issues https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2695#issuecomment-627714284

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS streams are GREAT for ETL work, but while very powerful they're also pretty complex and it's easy to get lost when when you're starting from scratch--as you have already experienced. I was looking for an easy way to use streams them while also allowing for code reuse; I ended up creating [gulp-etl](https://gulpetl.com/), which uses streams under the hood. Using gulp-etl, you could use the [gulp-etl-handlelines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-etl-handlelines) plugin, which calls a callback for each incoming record; if you want a single incoming record to produce multiple records it would look something like this:

```js
const handleLines = require('gulp-etl-handlelines').handlelines;

const linehandler = (lineObj, context) => {
    let recsToReturn = [];
 
    // return null to remove this line
    if (!lineObj.record || lineObj.record["TestValue"] == 'illegalValue') 
          {return null}
 
    // return incoming record
    recsToReturn.push(lineObj);

    // logic to create new record
    if (lineObj.record.needsDuplication) {
        // clone newRec from lineObj
        let newRec = {...lineObj, record:...lineObj.record};
        // change new record as needed
        newRec.record.UniqueField = "newValue";
        recsToReturn.push(newRec);
    }
 
    // return the record(s)
    return recsToReturn;
}

exports.default = function() {
    return src('data/100kRecs.ndjson', { buffer:false /* use streaming mode */})
    // pipe the files through our handlelines plugin
    .pipe(handlelines({}, { transformCallback: linehandler }))
    .pipe(dest('output/'));
}
```

We're using Transform streams behind the scenes, but that's all abstracted away; you get the benefits without having to get into the weeds of streams implementation--unless you want to write your own plugins. Plus, you can use lots of existing plugins.